# js onclick event is not working for my portfolio

Tags: javascript, onclick, thumbnails, portfolio

My js onclick event is not working for my portfolio. The page can be seen here: http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/branding and this is the script:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var portDefault = 'bonya';
    $('#portItem').hide();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $('#portItem').load('http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portDefault + ' #portLoadedContent', function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
    $('a.focusElement').focus();
});
function get_portfolio(portLocation) {
    $('#portItem').fadeOut();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $('#portItem').load('http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portLocation + ' #portLoadedContent', function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

The loading animation appears, but no image. Any thoughts are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is no click listener in your code... are you trying to display the loading animationand then go straight into the image load, or is there an actual user-supplied click that occurs in between?

Comment: where in your code did you declare the click() event handler?

Comment: You're trying to load the *raw data* of an image into your div. Try returning some HTML instead with an `img` tag, or return the image src and use jQuery to create a new `img` element

Comment: the onclick is for anchor elements on their page, that call get_portfolio()

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @Christian Varga's comment, you need to return HTML with the source set as the link you create. Try something like:

```
$("#portItem").html($("<img>")
                        .attr("src", 'http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portLocation + '#portLoadedContent'));
```

instead of your .load() line.

So I guess your final function should be something like:

```
function get_portfolio(portLocation) {
    $('#portItem').fadeOut();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $("#portItem").html($("<img>")
                             .attr("src", 'http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portLocation + '#portLoadedContent'));
    // UPDATE:
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    }, 1000);
});
```

}

Comment: doesn't the fadeIn() and fadeOut()'s cancel each other? there was no callback implemented to check if the image was loaded completely before firing the fadeOut() and fadeIn()'s at the bottom of the code... please check this issue.

Comment: @DexterHuinda you're right - I didn't realize that exactly, but i wasn't sure how to check if the <img> loaded or not. i guess using a setTimeout for like 1 second, in between adding the <img> and doing the fading at the end.

Comment: @ianpgall you can use .load() to check for the completion. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="portItem"><img /></div>
```

​JS:

```
$(function() {
    var portDefault = 'bonya';
    $('#portItem').hide();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
        $('#portItem img').attr("src",'http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portDefault + '#portLoadedContent');
    $('#portItem img').load(function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
});
function get_portfolio(portLocation) {
    $('#portItem').hide();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $('#portItem img').attr("src",'http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portLocation + '#portLoadedContent');

    //check if image is loaded, then hide loader + show image:

    $('#portItem img').load(function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

See demo : http://jsfiddle.net/esqmr/1/

Comment: If you look at the jQuery API page for .load(), it's not a great way to check for image loading: It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser, It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before, It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree, Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache.

Comment: @ianpgall so what do you suggest, if there is any?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the space before #portLoadedContent

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var portDefault = 'bonya';
    $('#portItem').hide();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $('#portItem').load('http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portDefault + '#portLoadedContent', function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
    $('a.focusElement').focus();
});
function get_portfolio(portLocation) {
    $('#portItem').fadeOut();
    $('#portLoader').fadeIn();
    $('#portItem').load('http://www.savantgenius.com/portfolio/portfolio-item/' + portLocation + '#portLoadedContent', function() {
        $('#portLoader').fadeOut();         
        $('#portItem').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Comment: this will fail also since the return content is an image, not HTML (see the comments above)